# Provable Data Possession

Tags: integrity

While Provable Data Possession seems to be a very useful and interesting tool for ensuring integrity of data outsourced into Cloud providers, I have never seen a reputed Cloud provider talk about this in their products.

Is this tech purely academic or what are restrictions which cause the lack of adoption of PDP ?